# Error: "List of Tensors when single Tensor expected" in computing a polynomial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate a polynomial using TensorFlow Python API as the following:

Polynomial: f(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4.

The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=())
cfc = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=5)

polynomial = tf.constant([1, x, tf.pow(x, 2), tf.pow(x, 3), tf.pow(x, 4)])
f = tf.tensordot(cfc, polynomial, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(f, feed_dict={x: 1.0,
                                    cfc: [0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0]})
    print(result)
```

A piece of quite simple code but I can't get it right.

Here is the error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/trytf/sandbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    polynomial = tf.constant([1, x, tf.pow(x, 2), tf.pow(x, 3), tf.pow(x, 4)])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 442, in make_tensor_proto
_AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 350, in _AssertCompatible
raise TypeError("List of Tensors when single Tensor expected")
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I don't understand why it says there is a list of tensors. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace the tf.constant with tf.stack because you can't pass the list of tensor as argument of tf.constant

`polynomial = tf.stack([1, x, tf.pow(x, 2), tf.pow(x, 3), tf.pow(x, 4)])`

Comment: Thanks. It works and the explanation is also what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this also hold for tf.cast or tf.math.count_nonzero ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to create a constant using x, which is a placeholder which accepts value at runtime. Thus it is throwing you that error.

Here is a modified version of the code that returns a result when run on Google Colab.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=())
cfc = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(5))

polynomial = tf.Variable([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
polynomial_op = polynomial.assign([1.0, x, tf.pow(x, 2), tf.pow(x, 3), tf.pow(x, 4)])
f = tf.tensordot(cfc, polynomial, 1)

init_op = tf.variables_initializer([polynomial])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    result = sess.run(polynomial_op, feed_dict={x: 2.0, cfc: [0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0]})
    print(result)

sess.close()
```

Result:

```
[ 1.  2.  4.  8. 16.]
```

Here, I defined polynomial as a Variable, and initialized it with the tf variables initializer. Note that since I am doing that, I assigned a default value in the beginning and then reassigned it the value that would be computed with x by defining an assignment operation and then running that. You can choose to do it with any other comfortable way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=())
cfc = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=5)
polynomial = [1, x, x**2, x**3, x**4]
f = tf.tensordot(cfc, polynomial, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(f, feed_dict={x: 1.0, cfc: [0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0]})
    print(result)
```